# Firebug Disable warnings from single javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebug

I am using jquery and jquery ui.
During development firefox throws many warnings for jquery .js and .css files and overflows console.

What I want to do is to filter all warnings from jquery-ui files (and probably from other libraries).

I have already tried:

- Disabling all warnings, but I do not see warnings from my files.
- Prefixing all my files with "fanta_" prefix, and puting "fanta_" in
  firebug filter, but it does not shows errors from other libraries.
- Most of errors are from loading jquery ui. I can clear them with console.clear() in $(document).load(), but I loose load warnings from my own scripts.

Is there a better/other way?

I use jquery ui, which comes with its own jquery, but I also use other libraries: 
 - jQuery UI - v1.10.3 - 2013-08-29
 - jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1 Date: 2013-2-4
 - jquery.csv-0.71.js
example error is (translated from Polish):

```
Error during processing value for „filter”.  Declaration skipped.
http://localhost/ext/jquery-ui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-custom.css
Line 920
```

Comment: Why so many warnings from jQuery? The only time I see one is when my own code is the cause.

Comment: Do the warnings appear when you use jQuery, or when you load jQuery?  You might be able to add console.clear() after the jQuery load.  I agree with Mike W, though, I never see warnings.  What version are you using?

Comment: I have added console.clear() which removed most of warnings. There should be <script>console.clear()</script> just after all external libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see JavaScript warnings coming from your jQuery file, then you should turn off the [Console panel option *Strict Warnings*](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Options_Menu).
This option doesn't change the display of CSS errors like the one you listed, though.

Filtering log messages coming from specific URLs is currently not possible in Firebug, though [issue 2955](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=2955) requests this feature called "black boxing".

Also there is [issue 4885](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4885), which describes black boxing JavaScripts in the debugger, i.e. they should be ignored while debugging.

As a temporary workaround you can simply comment out your jQuery UI CSS file to see just the CSS errors coming from your own files.

Another solution would be to load the jQuery related files before your own ones and call `console.clear()` as soon as the jQuery script is loaded, so within an event handler listening to the `onload` event of the script. That doesn't guarantee, though, that all errors from your files will be listed after clearing the console because of the asynchronous loading of CSS and JavaScript files.

Sebastian